# beamer hyperlinks not correct

Tags: beamer, hyperref, bookmarks, viewers

I've got the following problem. When clicking on a section in a presentation using hyperref, I'm not brought to the page itself, but a little bit below. What could be causing this?
[image]

MWE as follows.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\title[]{MWE}
\begin{document}
\section{VAA}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{John Doe}
\begin{frame}[t]{Slide 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{Slide 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{Slide 1}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The screenshot looks like PDF bookmarks which are created by sections, but  your MWE has different sections! Which PDF viewer do you use?

Comment: BTW: You don't have to load `hyperref` explicitly, as this is already done by `beamer`.

Comment: @JosephWright, I use Okular. Yes, my MWE has different sections. I used a picture of my complete document but then cut out everything that was unnecessary for the MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a viewer issue: Compiling your MWE with pdfLaTeX, this is the link position of the bookmark VAA I get in the resulting PDF file:

```
% 10 0 obj
<<
/D [18 0 R /XYZ 28.346 272.126 null]
>>
```

Converting the coordinates `28.346 272.126` given in PostScript points to centimetres yields a position of `(1cm, 9.6cm)` relative to the lower left corner of the paper, which is exactly `1cm` to the right of the upper left corner (as the default `beamer` papersize is `12.8cm x 9.6cm`). This shift is due to the page margins set by the document class.

So the bookmark should take you a little bit more to the *right* at most, but not *lower* than expected as you describe.

Anyway, if this really bugs you, you can try replacing the destination of the bookmark with a direct reference to the page anchor, which should take you exactly to the upper left corner. This can be done by patching the internal commands producing the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@part}{Outline\the\c@part}{page.\the\c@page}{}{}
\patchcmd{\beamer@section}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}{page.\the\c@page}{}{}
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsection}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}{page.\the\c@page}{}{}
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsubsection}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@subsubsection.\the\c@page}{page.\the\c@page}{}{}
\makeatother
\title[]{MWE}
\begin{document}
\section{VAA}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{John Doe}
\begin{frame}[t]{Slide 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{Slide 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{Slide 1}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I don't know if it's worth the effort, however - after all, presentations are normally given in full screen mode where bookmarks are often not available. Furthermore, `beamer` itself offers excellent navigation features like hyperlinked headlines, which are much more elegant in use than most viewer's built-in functions.

Comment: Cheers diabonas. It looks like a viewer issue, you're right. I've been testing it in other viewers. However, I'm having trouble with beamer's excellent navigation features. The navigate sections buttons don't behave exactly how I expect them to. I have three slides for three sections. They don't work on the first slide, on the second slide forward they work fine, moving 3 slides (2,5,8). Moving backwards, it goes from (8,7,4,1). Thus, I thought about using the "bookmarks"

Comment: @EricR Sounds weird... Can you give a MWE for this behaviour, possibly as a new question? Maybe it's a `beamer` issue that can be fixed.